# How to make a lightning data table button not clickable after click

Tags: lightning-web-components, js

I have a lightning data table with columns; inside these columns i have a button.
My problem is: i want to disable the button after it is clicked, i tried setting the value, but it's like i work on a copy of the actual value.
I'll show you the code.

Here there are the columns of the data table:

```
var columns = [ 
{ label: 'File Name', fieldName: 'Title'},
{ label: 'ID', fieldName: 'Id', type: 'id' },
{ label: 'Created Date', fieldName: 'CreatedDate', type: 'date', typeAttributes: {
    day: 'numeric',
    month: 'short',
    year: 'numeric',
    hour: '2-digit',
    minute: '2-digit',
    second: '2-digit',
    hour12: false
}, sortable: true},
{
    label: 'View',
    type: 'button',
    initialWidth: 135,
    typeAttributes: { label: 'View File', name: 'view_file', title: 'Click to View Details' }
},
{
    label: 'Download',
    type: 'button-icon',
    initialWidth: 135,
    typeAttributes: { iconName: 'utility:download', name: 'download_file', title: 'Click to download' },
},
{
    label: 'Restore',
    type: 'button',
    initialWidth: 150,
    typeAttributes: { label: 'Restore Backup', name:'restore_backup', title: 'Click to restore backup', disabled: false},
}
];
```

Here is my class:

```
export default class Files_page extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
@api contentDocumentDescription;
@api isLoading = false;
@track results = [];
@track columns = columns;
@track sortBy='CreatedDate';
@track sortDirection='desc';
@wire(fetch_cd,{field : '$sortBy',sortOrder : '$sortDirection'}) cdList({error, data}) {
    if(data)
    this.results=Object.assign([], data);
    if(error)
    this.showToast('Error', 'There was an error during sorting of the column,\nPlease try again', 'error');
    }

//toggles on/off the lightning spinner animation
toggleSpinner() { 
    this.isLoading = !this.isLoading;
}

//sorts columns
updateColumnSorting(event){ 
    let fieldName = event.detail.fieldName;
    let sortDirection = event.detail.sortDirection;
    this.sortBy = fieldName;
    this.sortDirection = sortDirection;
}

//handles different inputs from the user based on the button clicked;
handleRowAction(event){  
    var action = event.detail.action;
    var row = event.detail.row;
    switch (action.name) {
        case 'view_file':
            this.navigateToFiles(row.Id);
            break;
        case 'download_file':
            this.downloadFile(row.Id);
            break;
        case 'restore_backup':
            this.restoreCSV(row);
            this.toggleSpinner();
            this.columns[5]['typeAttributes']['disabled'] = true;
            break;
        default:
            this.navigateToFiles(row.Id);
            break;
    }
}
```

As you can see i tried to do this.columns[5]['typeAttributes']['disabled'] = true; but it doesn't work.

My code continues, so if you see variables declared that are not used, it's normal; anyway i want to disable the button with the lable "Restore" (the last one) after is clicked.
Another thing is: i put my columns before the starting of the class, i don't know if this influences the behaviour.

Thanks in advance for your time

Comment: Have you tried creating a variable and changing boolean value? I mean instead disabled: false -> disabled: flag. Based on your condition set flag to true or flase, I haven't tried it but please try and let me know if it works. Or please put a spinner so user will not able to click anywhere.

Comment: i tried but it doesn't work